# insert masonry in php from images that were retreieved from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, masonry

I would like to insert masonry into a php form that retrieves images from a MySQL database. I can retrieve the images, but when I try to put in masonry, the whole thing doesn't work at all.

Here is my code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM img");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<script src="/path/to/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>"
  echo "<div id="container">"
  echo "<img class='item' src='" . $row['path'] . "' />";
  echo "</div>"
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 issues with that code:

First of all, you don't really have to include your script for every new `<div>`. Just include your script once in the `<head>` section, as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/path/to/masonry" />
        ...
    </head>
```

Secondly, you need to differentiate between `"` as a string container in your PHP code and as a character that should appear in your final HTML code. When using it as the latter, you need to escape it by adding a backslash (like so: `\"`), or simply replace it with an apostrophe:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM img");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<div id='container'>";
  echo "<img class='item' src='" . $row['path'] . "' />";
  echo "</div>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And finally, as presented in the example, you forgot the semicolon terminator at the end of your lines of code inside the `while` loop.